Daisy UI with Vue 3 - Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js): TypeError: Object.hasOwn is not a function
I created a vue 3 project with tailwind. After adding daisyui as a plugin, I can't compile it.
Errors I get
in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=css

Syntax Error: TypeError: Object.hasOwn is not a function
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)


ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12.use[2]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: Object.hasOwn is not a function

tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
  purge: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
}

Node version: v19.9.0
Daisy UI: 4.11.1
Tailwind: 3.4.3
I updated the node version, since Object.hasOwn is only availible in Node>16
But I still have the errors

Try using NodeJS v20.

Did you completely uninstall your previous version of Node before installing new one?  Does node -v in terminal show v19?  BTW, I don't think it should affect your issue but it's recommended to use even numbered versions of Node because only even version numbers include long term support. If you confirm node is actually upgraded, please then edit your question to include your full package.json.

Also: https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui/issues/2247#issuecomment-1676147274
